# firebase - interacting with other web APIs

Tags: php, firebase

I am currently using an Apache Server and a MySQL database hosted for development purposes on Cloud9 as a means of authenticating and storing user data for a development Android app. I have begun to learn Firebase, which could make interactions with my databases easier and more efficient.

However, in my research into Firebase, I cannot figure out how to do the one operation that Apache Server performed that didn't involve interacting with my database: connecting to other web APIs. In particular, I was connecting with the [NHTSA Vehicle API](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home) to get more information about a vehicle before storing it in my database. Here is the small chunk of code I used to interact with this API:

```
function identify($vin) {
    $postdata = http_build_query(array("format"=>"json", "data"=>$vin));
    $options = array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET", "content" => $postdata));
    $url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValuesExtended/".$vin."?format=json";

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $request = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    $response = stream_get_contents($request);

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

How can I implement this type of function into Firebase?

Comment: If you can call the API from within your web page with that code, what do you want to do with Firebase?

Comment: I wanted to move completely to Firebase. Managing HTTP calls for every database write and read is tedious work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "moving completely to Firebase". Can you describe how you'd expect to consume this data in that scenario?

Comment: I want to store vehicle information in my database based on the vin that comes from my Android app. I want to take advantage of NHTSA's database to get that information. Now the user can scroll through there vehicle recognizing the make, model, and year of their vehicle. I used PHP and MySQL to do this previously, but I want to use Firebase for my database now. I was wondering if I could avoid needing my Apache Server altogether and use Firebase to communicate with NHTSA's API also.

Comment: You could use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to call the NHTSA's API.